# Python find strings and replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have string in Python :

**`s = "htmlhtl {% static path1 %} htmlhtml {% static path2/path3 %} htmlhtml "`**

and variable :

**`path = "www.static.com"`**

I want to make from **s** new string which will contain on the places of the **`{% static ... %}`** tag paths to folders:

```
"htmlhtl www.static.com/path1 htmlhtml www.static.com/path2/path3 htmlhtml"
```

I have opened python doc, and have tried to do it by myself but I can't even match tags. The task seems to be very often case for regexp.

Comment: Is this django? What is the error you are getting? If it is django, did you do {% load static %} beforehand in your template?

Comment: Yes, It's django, I want to do it manually and place my file to string to prevent any attempts of django to read it from disk each time. Cause is that file too small and very often client demand him.

Comment: I can't use cache because I don't need in cache at all, my site have only one page which continue interact with site by using Angular REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `Django`'s builtin methods or a simple regex to achieve the same:

```
import re

s = "htmlhtl {% static path1 %} htmlhtml {% static path2/path3 %} htmlhtml " 

rx = re.compile(r'{% static (?P<path>\S+) %}')
# search for {% static ...%}

s = rx.sub(r'www.static.com/\g<path>', s)
print(s)
# htmlhtl www.static.com/path1 htmlhtml www.static.com/path2/path3 htmlhtml
```

---

See a working [**demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/goHBdl).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you give me some links to learn regexp in Python?

Comment: @LuchkoSerega Glad it worked. A good starting point is http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/632/regular-expressions-regex#t=201610261924366282161

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example solution I came up with to your provided information using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "htmlhtl {% static path1 %} htmlhtml {% static path2/path3 %} htmlhtml "
>>> path = "www.static.com"
>>> pat = re.compile(r'\{%\s*static\s+([\w/]+)\s*%\}')
>>> re.sub(pat, path+r'/\1',s)
'htmlhtl www.static.com/path1 htmlhtml www.static.com/path2/path3 htmlhtml '
```